# how to get the key/value pairs from a JsonResult object in c#?

Tags: json, c#-4.0

i get a JsonResult object in my ASP.NET MVC project, its Data property is a json string like this:

```
"{\"Name\":\"Paul\", \"Age\":\"23\"}";
```

how can i get the key/value pairs about this string in c#? i mean i can get the value via each key. thanks in advance!

Comment: read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c)

Comment: great, that works fine~